# Map each array element into a different function

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Is there a way to **directly map** each element in an array into a separate function and return the result of each function into a separate variable for that element?

For example, I have this code:

```
arry = ["22-03-1995", 80.5, 1.83];

born   = process_date(arry[0]);     // call specific function for 1st element
weight = process_weight(arry[1]);   // call specific function for 2nd element
height = process_height(array[2]);  // call specific function for 3rd element

...

function process_date(d) { ... }
function process_weight(w) { ... }
function process_height(h) { ... }
```

or such an alternative method to achieve the same in a better shorter form.

Comment: Which result would you expect based on provided input?

Comment: I think your best bet would be a function that takes the array as an argument, runs the 3 functions, and returns an object with the results as properties. array.map only supports one callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there's only one array you want to map then you probably want something like this:

```
const [born, weight, height] = [
  process_date(arry[0]),
  process_weight(arry[1]),
  process_height(array[2])
]
```

if there are multiple arrays then that needs its own handling, you can create a function that takes the input array and returns the mapped array:

```
function mapArray(arr) {
  return [
    process_date(arr[0]),
    process_weight(arr[1]),
    process_height(arr[2])
  ]
}

arry.forEach(arr => {
  const [born, weight, height] = mapArray(arr);
  // do stuff with the variables here...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this. Might help you somehow.
You can destruct your each arrays element and assign them to a new variable. Aswel you can pass array to function as arguments.
https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 1):

You could put your functions into an object.  Then put your values into an array of objects, so that you can have metadata to tell the value what function it should call.

Example

```
const valueObjects = [{
    type: "date",
    value: "22-03-1995"
}, {
    type: "weight",
    value: 80.5
}]

const calculations = {
    date: function process_date(d) {...},
    weight: function process_weight(w) {...}
};

valueObjects.forEach(valueObject => {
    const processType = calculations[valueObject.type];
    processType(valueObject.value);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you

```
arry = ["22-03-1995", 80.5, 1.83];
arrayFunc = [function process_date(d) { ... }, function process_weight(w) { ... },  function process_height(h) { ... } ]

array.forEach(myFunction);

let results = []
function myFunction(item, index) {
  results << arrayFunc[index](item)
} 

let born, weight, height; 
[born, weight, height] = results;

console.log(born);
console.log(weight);
console.log(height);
```